# How to save github actions output to the repo?

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to use pandoc to convert markdown files pushed to my repo into pdfs. But, not sure how to save the output to my repo.

Here's my code:

```yaml
name: pandoc

on: push

jobs: 
  convert_via_pandoc:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: convert md to pdf 
      uses: docker://pandoc/latex:2.9
      with:
        entrypoint: /bin/sh
        run: |
         cd markdown-files; 
         for file in $(ls ./ |grep *.md); do 
          pandoc $file -o ${file:0:-2}pdf; 
          done
```

Comment: If you just want to add the pdf files to the repo, you can use git commands to add, commit and push the files at the end of the workflow.

Answer (score 8):

You can simply push it back to the repository by committing it with one of the actions available on Marketplace:

```
- uses: stefanzweifel/git-auto-commit-action@v4
  with:
      commit_message: Changed files
```

Alternatively, you can upload your data as an artifact to your workflow:
https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact

```
- uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
  with:
    name: pdfs
    path: path/to/pdfs/
```

Comment: But, artifacts are not added to the repo right?

Comment: Nope, if you need them in repo - use the commit step - first one in my answer.